# Getting HTTP 400 Bad request while POST request using urllib

Tags: python-3.x

Getting HTTP 400 bad request from testrail server when i try to post testcase result using urllib in python3. Appreciate if someone help me on this. Thanks!

Below is code,

```
import urllib.request
import json
import base64

data = {'results':[{'case_id': '123','status_id': '1','comment': 'This test passed', 'version': '0.14.0-W9'}]}
headers = {}
post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(data).encode()
auth = base64.b64encode(b'user:pass')
auth = auth.decode()
headers['Authorization'] = 'Basic %s' % auth
headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
request = urllib.request.Request("http://testrail.com/index.php?/api/v2/add_results_for_cases/272374", data = post_data, headers = headers)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
result = json.loads(response)
print(result)
```

And error output,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p3.py", line 13, in <module>
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request).read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: Maybe you are using their api incorrectly see the response message that may provide some details.

Comment: It's advisable to use the `requests` library instead of re-inventing the wheel (and thus increasing the chance of doing something wrong) with all that manual encoding and decoding.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tomalak and Amiy for quick suggestions. 
I have tried testrailAPI library of python3 and it works as expected.